# Creating array lists using Json object file in android

Tags: java, android

Please check out my following code

```
String jsonString = writer.toString();
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonString); 
        defaultCurrencyValue = jsonObj.getString(DefaultCurrencyKey);
        currenciesTypes = jsonObj.get(CurrenciesKey);
```

This is what i get the values of curenciesType object class variable when i used Debugger

```
currenciesTypes JSONObject  (id=830084916104)   
    myHashMap   HashMap  (id=830084916120)  
        [0] HashMap$HashMapEntry  (id=830084916440) 
            key "PKR" (id=830084916256) 
            value   "Rs" (id=830084916368)  
        [1] HashMap$HashMapEntry  (id=830084917208) 
            key "EUR" (id=830084917064) 
            value   "€" (id=830084917176)   
        [2] HashMap$HashMapEntry  (id=830084916696) 
        [3] HashMap$HashMapEntry  (id=830084916952)
```

Please anyone can tell me how can i save  `key` and its `values` in two array lists?

Best Regards

Comment: why you need two different array lists..you can store it within one array list..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have two arraylists say keys, and values:

```
String jsonString = writer.toString();
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonString); 
         currenciesTypes = jsonObj.get(CurrenciesKey);
        ArrayList<String> keys=new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> values=new ArrayList<String>();
        Iterator<String> iterator=currencyType.keys();
        while(iterator.hasNext())
        {
              String key=iterator.next();
              keys.add(key);
              values.add(currencyType.get(key));
        }
```

Comment: Awesome solution. Just used it in combination with a HashMap. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

@user966227 :

Hey, refer this link it will definitely help you out....

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidJSON/article.html

In this page tutorial of getting data from JSON file into array is shown. But i think you can use that for converting into array list also...

Comment: look i have a JSONOBJECT Class variable currenciesTypes , from it, i want to retrieve both key and value. I can get value if i use variable.get(Key). But here in this case, i want to store key too in an array

Answer (score 2):

```
    String jsonString = writer.toString();
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonString); 
    JSONObject currenciesTypes = jsonObj.get(CurrenciesKey);
    List<Pair<String,String>> keyValuePairList=new ArrayList<Pair<String,String>>();
    Iterator<String> iterator=currenciesTypes.keys();
    while(iterator.hasNext())
    {
       String key=iterator.next();
       Pair<String,String> keyValue=new Pair<String,String>(key, (String) currenciesTypes.get(key));
       keyValuePairList.add(keyValue);
    }
```